# How to redirect to login after ajax call in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a like button that is visible to all users, but i only want authenticated users to be able to like and unlike the product. If a guest tries to like, i would like to redirect them to login page.

Blade File

```
 <div style="display: {{$product->isLiked ? "" : "none"}}" id="deletefavourite{{$product->id}}"onClick="deleteFromFavourites({{$product->id}}, {{   Auth::user()->id }})"> unlike </div>
<div style=" display: {{!$product->isLiked ? "" : "none"}}" id="addfavourites{{$product->id}}" onClick="addToFavourites({{$product->id}}, {{ Auth::user()->id }})" > like </div>
```

Javascript

```
  function addToFavourites(productid, userid) {
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
});

$.ajax({
method: 'post',
url: `/product/like/${productid}`,
data: {
    'user_id': userid,
    'product_id': productid,
},
success: function () {
    // hide add button
console.log($('#addfavourites' + productid));
    $('#addfavourites' + productid).show();
    // show delete button
    $('#deletefavourite' + productid).show();
},
error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
    // handle error
}
});

}
```

Like Controller

```
  public function likeProduct($id)
{


    if(Auth::check()){
    $this->handleLike(Product::class, $id);
    return redirect()->back();
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->route('login')
    }
}

public function handleLike($type, $id)
{
    $existing_like = Like::withTrashed()->whereLikeableType($type)->whereLikeableId($id)->whereUserId(Auth::id())->first();

    if (is_null($existing_like)) {
        Like::create([
            'user_id'       => Auth::id(),
            'likeable_id'   => $id,
            'product_id'   => $id,
            'likeable_type' => $type,
        ]);
    } else {
        if (is_null($existing_like->deleted_at)) {
            $existing_like->delete();
        } else {
            $existing_like->restore();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to `(Auth::check()` on controller but this only hides the button. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better option would be not to redirect but return an unauthorized error, catch that error in JS and redirect to the login page.

```
error: function (xhr) {
  if (xhr.status == 401) {
    window.location.href = '/path/to/login';
  }
}
```

Besides this you would need to return a 401 status code on the controller.

```
else{
  abort(401, 'You need to login again.');
}
```

Comment: I have tried to put that code in js `//handle error` but is not working @Aza Rnglab

Comment: I've fixed the JS code, be sure to also add the status code to the controller.

Comment: abort(401) so the js side detects an error with the ajax call

Comment: So it is like this before even user clicks the button if is not authenticated it shows an error `Trying to get property of non object` but I want even a guest to see the button.(user can't see the button until he login) @Aza Rnglab

Comment: the `window.location.href = '/path/to/login';` should redirect them to the login page

Comment: I mean if I go to the homepage where there is a like button( non authenticated user sees an error `Trying to get property of non-object` because this line `{{ Auth::user()->id }})" > like </div>` needs a login user to send the user_id , how do I fix this I want a guest to see the button before clicking @Aza Rnglab

Comment: `Auth::user()` returns no user so you probably need to check before. Either override the user method of Auth to return a dummy guest user with id = 0, create a presenter for the user id or simply do `Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->id : 0`

Comment: Okay , this looks good but how do I get this `abort(401, 'You need to login again.');`  in blade I mean the message `You need to login again` because this doesn't work `@if(session('success'))` @Aza Rnglab

Comment: But thanks anyway, it solved the problem @Aza Rnglab

Comment: Welcome, sorry i cannot be of more help